# [Example(), Example1()) multiple commands error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

i"m having trouble understanding this error and even more trying to fix it.
I have 3 buttons, Paper, Rock and Scissors. They were previously only linked to my Game()
but since I made a function called Delete to delete my label that kept repeating the message.
I added it but i get errors i can't even understand

```
    File "c:\Users\MiroP\WUA\Random.py", line 105, in <lambda>
        (ScissorsButton := Button(root, image = scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=lambda:[Game(player_choice_string=Game), Delete()]("scissors"))).pack(pady=10)
      File "c:\Users\MiroP\WUA\Random.py", line 100, in Game
        win_lose_tie_label = Label(root, text="Your choice was: "+player_choice_string+" and the enemy's choice was: "+computer_input, font=("Verdana", 5),bg = "white", bd=0).pack()       
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "function") to str
```

my code:

```
    #Import List
    from ast import Delete
    from sqlite3 import Row
    from tkinter import *
    from random import randint
    from tkinter import font
    from tkinter.tix import COLUMN
    from turtle import color
    from tkinter import ttk
    import random
    from PIL import ImageTk,Image
    #Basics
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Rock Paper Scissors -Made by Trapgrave")
    root.iconbitmap("c:/images/star.ico")
    root.config(bg="white")
    
        #Images
    rock = PhotoImage(file="c:/images/rock.png")
    paper = PhotoImage(file="c:/images/paper.png")
    scissors = PhotoImage(file="c:/images/scissors.png")
    rock = PhotoImage(file="c:/images/rock.png")
    paper = PhotoImage(file="c:/images/paper.png")
    scissors = PhotoImage(file="c:/images/scissors.png")
        #-
    Choose = Label(root, font=("Roboto", 15), text = "Rock, Paper, Scissors!", bg="white").pack(side = TOP)
    
        #Storing points
    user_points = 0
    computer_points = 0
        #Options
    
    def Delete():
        user_points.destroy()
        win_lose_tie_label.destroy()
    def Game(player_choice_string):
        print("player chose: {}".format(player_choice_string))
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        global user_points, computer_points
    
        options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
        computer_input = random.choice(options)
    
        if player_choice_string == "rock":
            if computer_input == "rock":
                print("Your input is rock")
                print("Computer input is rock")
                print("It is a tie!")
            elif computer_input == "paper":
                print("Your input is rock")
                print("Computer input is paper")
                print("you lost!")
                computer_points += 1
            elif computer_input == "scissors":
                print("Your input is rock")
                print("Computer input is scissors")
                print("you win!")
                user_points += 1
    
        elif player_choice_string == "paper":
            if computer_input == "rock":
                print("Your input is paper")
                print("Computer input is rock")
                print("You win!")
                user_points += 1
            elif computer_input == "paper":
                print("Your input is paper")
                print("Computer input is paper")
                print("It is a tie!")
            elif computer_input == "scissors":
                print("Your input is paper")
                print("Computer input is scissors")
                print("you lost!")
                user_points += 1
    
        elif player_choice_string == "scissors":
            if computer_input == "rock":
                print("Your input is scissors")
                print("Computer input is rock")
                print("You lost!")
                computer_points += 1
            elif computer_input == "paper":
                print("Your input is scissors")
                print("Computer input is paper")
                print("You win!")
                user_points += 1
            elif computer_input == "scissors":
                print("Your input is scissors")
                print("Computer input is scissors")
                print("It is a tie!")   
        global points_label
        global win_lose_tie_label
        points_label = Label(root, text="You have "+ str(user_points) + " and the enemy now has: " + str(computer_points) + "!", bg="white", bd=0).pack()
        win_lose_tie_label = Label(root, text="Your choice was: "+player_choice_string+" and the enemy's choice was: "+computer_input, font=("Verdana", 5),bg = "white", bd=0).pack()
    
    
    (RockButton := Button(root, image = rock, bg="white", bd=0,command=lambda:[Game(), Delete()]("rock"))).pack(side = LEFT)
    (PaperButton := Button(root, image = paper, bg="white", bd=0,command=lambda:[Game(), Delete()]("paper"))).pack(side = RIGHT)
    (ScissorsButton := Button(root, image = scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=lambda:[Game(), Delete()]("scissors"))).pack(pady=10)
    
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just like the error says: you can't add strings and non-strings. `player_choice_string` is a function because you do `player_choice_string=Game` and `Game` is a function.

Comment: Note that the posted code does not match the code in the posted exception.

Comment: it is not preferred to use `[ ]` to run code. Better create normal function with `Game(), Delete()` - and then you can add `print()` to see which function is executed and what you get in variables.

Comment: BTW it should be `[Game("rock"), Delete()]` instead of `[Game(), Delete()]("rock")`

Comment: error shows you in which line you have problem - so you could use `print()`, `print(type())`, etc. to see what you have in variables in this line. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what can make problem.

Comment: @trapgrave. Does this help? in line 100. text=f"Your choice was: {player_choice_string} and the enemy's choice was: {computer_input}",

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows different code than you show in question.

But it also show that problem can be because you use wrong values.

Error shows

```
[Game(player_choice_string=Game), Delete()]("scissors")
```

so you assign function to variable `player_choice_string=Game` and later your `"text"+player_choice_string+"text"` means `"text"+Game+"text"`

It should be

```
[Game("scissors"), Delete()]
```

I thin you wouldn't have this problem if you would use normal function instead of `[ ]`

```
def func_game():
    Game("scissors")
    Delete()

ScissorsButton = Button(root, image=scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=func_game)
ScissorsButton.pack(pady=10)
```

---

But all this code will have always the same problem. It will create labels and later delete them and you will not see these labels - because tkinter first executes all your functions and later it redraw widgets in window.

It would need `root.update()` inside code to redraw widgets. And it may need `sleep(1)` to display it for some time (1s).

```
def func_game():
    Game("scissors")
    root.update()   # force `tkinter` to redraw widgets in window
    # after 1s run `Delete()`
    time.sleep(1)
    Delete()

ScissorsButton = Button(root, image=scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=func_game)
ScissorsButton.pack(pady=10)
```

Or it would need `root.after(1000, function_name)` to display it - tkinter will have time to redraw window.

```
def func_game():
    Game("scissors")
    # after 1000ms (1s) run `Delete()`
    root.after(1000, Delete)  # function's name without ()

ScissorsButton = Button(root, image=scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=func_game)
ScissorsButton.pack(pady=10)
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @acw1668 said in comment: better suggestion is to create labels with empty strings at the beginning, and later only replace text

```
points_label.config(text=f"You have {user_points} and the enemy now has: {computer_points}!")
win_lose_tie_label.config(text=f"Your choice was: {player_choice_string} and the enemy's choice was: {computer_input}")
```

and later remove text

```
points_label.config(text="")
win_lose_tie_label.config(text="")
```

---

Full code with my comments.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code
                     # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
                     
def game(player_input):
    global user_points          # PEP8: all `global` at the beginning of function (in separated lines
    global computer_points

    print(f"player chose: {player_input}")

    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computer_input = random.choice(options)

    if player_input == "rock":
        if computer_input == "rock":
            print("Your input is rock")
            print("Computer input is rock")
            print("It is a tie!")
        elif computer_input == "paper":
            print("Your input is rock")
            print("Computer input is paper")
            print("you lost!")
            computer_points += 1
        elif computer_input == "scissors":
            print("Your input is rock")
            print("Computer input is scissors")
            print("you win!")
            user_points += 1

    elif player_input == "paper":
        if computer_input == "rock":
            print("Your input is paper")
            print("Computer input is rock")
            print("You win!")
            user_points += 1
        elif computer_input == "paper":
            print("Your input is paper")
            print("Computer input is paper")
            print("It is a tie!")
        elif computer_input == "scissors":
            print("Your input is paper")
            print("Computer input is scissors")
            print("you lost!")
            user_points += 1

    elif player_input == "scissors":
        if computer_input == "rock":
            print("Your input is scissors")
            print("Computer input is rock")
            print("You lost!")
            computer_points += 1
        elif computer_input == "paper":
            print("Your input is scissors")
            print("Computer input is paper")
            print("You win!")
            user_points += 1
        elif computer_input == "scissors":
            print("Your input is scissors")
            print("Computer input is scissors")
            print("It is a tie!")
            
    points_label.config(text=f"You have {user_points} and the enemy now has: {computer_points}!")
    win_lose_tie_label.config(text=f"Your choice was: {player_input} and the enemy's choice was: {computer_input}")

    root.after(2000, delete)  # run after 2000ms (2s)
    
def delete():
    points_label.config(text="")
    win_lose_tie_label.config(text="")

# --- main ---   # PEP8 `lower_case_names` for variables

user_points = 0
computer_points = 0

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Rock Paper Scissors - Made by Trapgrave")
root.iconbitmap("c:/images/star.ico")
root.config(bg="white")

rock = tk.PhotoImage(file="c:/images/rock.png")
paper = tk.PhotoImage(file="c:/images/paper.png")
scissors = tk.PhotoImage(file="c:/images/scissors.png")

choose = tk.Label(root, font=("Roboto", 15), text="Rock, Paper, Scissors!", bg="white")
choose.pack(side='top')

# PEP8: inside `()` parameters without spaces around `=`
rock_button = tk.Button(root, image=rock, bg="white", bd=0, command=lambda:game("rock"))
rock_button.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)

paper_button = tk.Button(root, image=paper, bg="white", bd=0, command=lambda:game("paper"))
paper_button.pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)

scissors_button = tk.Button(root, image=scissors, bg="white", bd=0, command=lambda:game("scissors"))
scissors_button.pack(side='bottom', padx=10, pady=10)

points_label = tk.Label(root, text="", bg="white", bd=0)
points_label.pack()

win_lose_tie_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Verdana", 5), bg="white", bd=0)
win_lose_tie_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I think that better suggestion is to create the `points_label` and `win_lose_tie_label` once outside `Game()` and update their text inside the function, then don't need the `Delete()` function at all.

Comment: @acw1668 yes, it is also good idea. Later I will add this to answer.